# How to pass struct data in prepare for seque

Tags: swift

I get the following error when trying to pass data from one viewcontroller to another: "Cannot assign value of type 'activityTableViewController.request' to type 'activityDetailTableViewController.request?'"

What am I doing wrong?

First view controller:

```
class activityTableViewController: UITableViewController {

struct request {
    var fromDateAndTime: String
    var toDateAndTime: String
    var createdBy: String

    init(fromDateAndTime: String, toDateAndTime: String, createdBy: String) {
        self.fromDateAndTime = fromDateAndTime
        self.toDateAndTime = toDateAndTime
        self.createdBy = createdBy
    }
}

var requestList: [request] = []

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "activityToDetail" {
        if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? activityDetailTableViewController {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            nextViewController.requestDetail = requestList[indexPath!.row]
        }
    }
}

}
```

Second view controller:

```
class activityDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

struct request {
    var fromDateAndTime: String
    var toDateAndTime: String
    var createdBy: String

init(fromDateAndTime: String, toDateAndTime: String, createdBy: String)    {
        self.fromDateAndTime = fromDateAndTime
        self.toDateAndTime = toDateAndTime
        self.createdBy = createdBy
    }
}

var requestList: request!

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please conform to the naming convention that class and struct names start with a capital letter.

Both structs seem to be the same but they are different objects because they are declared in different name spaces.

Create **one** struct outside of any class and delete the initializer because you get it for free.

```
struct Request {
    var fromDateAndTime: String
    var toDateAndTime: String
    var createdBy: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to only have 1 `struct` as it will be visible inside all the app , and get it out of any class

```
struct Request {
    var fromDateAndTime,toDateAndTime,createdBy: String 
}
```

plus there is no need to write `init` inside a struct type , and start it with capital letter

> There is no availability to declare a struct with the same name as another it's a language logical constraint